# JSONObject not being correctly created (possible JSON formatting error?)

Tags: java, android, json

I am getting this JSON string:

```
[
{
    "id": 135,
    "date": "2013-08-30 19:00:29",
    "timestamp": "2013-08-30 19:00:29",
    "lat": "54.328274",
    "long": "-2.747215",
    "strap": "annual International Festival of Street Arts",
    "link": "http://dev.website.co.uk//?p=135",
    "title": "Title"
}
]
```

Which is correct JSON syntax im sure (works fine in the iOS app), however when parsing to a JSONObject it catches an error. Java:

```
public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url){

    //initialize
    InputStream is = null;   
    String result = "";   
    JSONObject jArray = null;

    //http post
    try {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();   
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);    
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        is = entity.getContent();    

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());   
    }
    //convert response to string

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);  
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();   
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {   
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {    
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
    //try parse the string to a JSON object

    try {
        Log.d("log_tag", "jresult: " + result + "finish");
        jArray = new JSONObject(result);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
    return jArray;
}
```

Is there an error somewhere in the JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[` represents a json array node

`{` represents a json object node

```
    JSONArray jArray  = new JSONArray(result);
    return jArray;
```

Also you can have one try block instead of many.

Comment: Thanks! Best explanation here, so thank you! I will accept it when it allows :)

Comment: @JoshBoothe you are welcome. also you can have one try block and have many catch block based on exception hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

It's an array, so you need to do "new JSONArray()" instead of "new JSONObject()".

Answer (score 0):

when a json string starts with `[` the it will be treated as a `JSONArray` you need to do `new JSONArray()`